# Mozilla keeps sending cursor position in contenteditable span to the beginning

Tags: html, css, mozilla

I have problem with Mozilla version 53.0.2 (32-bit).

When I click in the span to edit the text it moves my cursor in the beginning. I tried changing properties and css. I found also that this was a bug in previous versions but I dont know if it is still an issue

```
<td>

<span 
class="edit_notes"  
style="min-width: 1200px; display: inline-block;display:-moz-inline-box;-moz-user-select: element;" 
draggable="false" 
id="comment469"  
contenteditable="">

TEXT TO EDIT

</span>

</td>

#table1 td, tr, thead, tbody, thead, th {
    padding: 4px;
    text-align: left;
}
.table > tbody > tr > td, .table > tbody > tr > th, .table > tfoot > tr > td, .table > tfoot > tr > th, .table > thead > tr > td, .table > thead > tr > th {
    padding: 8px;
    line-height: 1.42857143;
    vertical-align: top;
    border-top: 1px solid #ddd;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have no problem in Firefox with positioning in spans, even as inline-blocks - I suspect your problem is that contenteditable should = either "true" or "false" - setting it to "" may be interpreted as false, hence you can't position in the span.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved,

I have discovered it was problem with javascript. 
Opera, Chrome, even Internet Explorer behaved good with this replacement but mozilla keeps sending caret to the beginning. After I changed the below code to the new one it works good.

//OLD

```
function clear_input(ID) {
  oldhtml = $("#comment" + ID).html().replace(/&nbsp;/g, "");
  var newhtml = oldhtml.replace(/&nbsp;/g, "");
  $("#comment" + ID).html(newhtml);
}
```

//NEW

```
function clear_input(ID) {
  $("#comment" + ID).html().replace(/&nbsp;/g, "");
}
```

Comment: The question did not even mention that you were using JavaScript. In order to make it helpful for other people, please consider incorporating that information to the question or removing it altogether.